# visual c++ multiple definitions of <limits> constants

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multiple-definition-error, one-definition-rule

I have one header and two source files.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "constant.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << test.at("Hello") << std::endl;
}
```

constant.h:

```
#ifndef CONSTANT_H
#define CONSTANT_H

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

extern std::unordered_map<std::string, int> const test;

#endif
```

constant.cpp:

```
#include "constant.h"

std::unordered_map<std::string, int> const test = {
    {"Hello", 1},
    {"World", 2}
};
```

When I compile with Visual C++(Visual Studio 2015 Update 1) I get lots of multiple definition linker errors.

EDIT: it only happens when the /Za(Disable Language Extensions) switch is enabled

All of them seem to originate from the <limits> header.

Here are the first few errors(sorry for german compiler output):

```
1>constant.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static bool const std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::is_signed" (?is_signed@?$numeric_limits@E@std@@2_NB) ist bereits in main.obj definiert.
1>constant.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits" (?digits@?$numeric_limits@E@std@@2HB) ist bereits in main.obj definiert.
1>constant.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits10" (?digits10@?$numeric_limits@E@std@@2HB) ist bereits in main.obj definiert.
1>constant.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static bool const std::numeric_limits<short>::is_signed" (?is_signed@?$numeric_limits@F@std@@2_NB) ist bereits in main.obj definiert.
1>constant.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const std::numeric_limits<short>::digits" (?digits@?$numeric_limits@F@std@@2HB) ist bereits in main.obj definiert.
1>constant.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static int const std::numeric_limits<short>::digits10" (?digits10@?$numeric_limits@F@std@@2HB) ist bereits in main.obj definiert.
```

However, when I compile the same code with Clang/C2 or with g++ or clang++ on linux, I don't get any linker errors.

Does this program violate the ODR and is Visual C++ correct in rejecting it?

Comment: maybe you can add example of error message?

Comment: Can't reproduce with VS 2015 pro. The turtle moves.

Comment: Also cannot reproduce with Qt 5.5 / MinGW 4.9.2 / CMake.

Comment: This sounds like a linker issue more than a compiler one, and doubly strange since one would expect these kinds of things to be `inline` anyway

Comment: Able to repro in VS Community with /Za. I also get `1>c:\dev\test\constant.cpp(3): warning C4592: 'test': symbol will be dynamically initialized (implementation limitation)`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a completely broken toolchain, especially since you didn't even directly include `<limits>` yourself. Apparently the "non-extended" mode of Visual Studio 2015 doesn't get quite as much testing as the "add lots of things to C++" mode.

FWIW, your code is fine.

Raise a bug on MS Connect.

Fortunately, you already have a workaround.